# Don't have permission to download to Program Files folder on PC

Tags: windows, directory, download

A few months ago I changed the download settings on my computer (Windows 10) so that whenever I download a file from the web, it prompts me to choose where I want to save it (e.g. Downloads, My Documents, Desktop, etc). Before changing the settings my computer would automatically save most program files to the Program Files folder (naturally). But today I was trying to download the Anaconda/Python software, and I figured I should save it to the Program Files folder. However, when I choose this folder at the download prompt it says "You don't have permission to save in this location. Contact the administrator to obtain permission." But this is on my laptop, and I am the sole user. So how don't I have permission/how can I obtain permission?

Also, I've encountered this issue a number of times since changing the download settings and I've been saving program files to C:/Users/Leonidas instead...Could there be any bad consequences to saving it here instead of in Program Files?

Comment: That does not really seam "natural". You should not download the files to hat location. If I understand it correctly, it might give them admin rights.

Comment: I have numerous folders in my Program Files folder--Adobe, Google, Internet Explorer, Java, Microsoft Office, a bunch of Windows folders...should those not be there?

Comment: Anaconda automatically saves in C:\Users\<your-username>\Anaconda3 for Windows. But it should not give problem while changing the location. You could maybe check the download file is the correct one or not.

Comment: @user1111 Thanks, I figured out how to switch my download settings back to the default and that is exactly where Anaconda was saved. After discussing my question with a more tech savvy friend, he explained to me that there is nothing special about the "Program Files" folder; it's just a name. Me being an uninformed luddite, I thought something bad might happen if I saved it in a folder that was not Program Files...Lol.